# Could internal exposure to electromagnetic radiation be contagious or leave a trace?

Tags: biology, physics, diseases, radiation

This is linked to another question I asked a few days ago but my story concerns an inter-dimensional consciousness that lures children into itself by manifesting as magical wonderlands with wacky characters (think a creepy Sesame Street or Lazy Town).

The real story starts with an adult survivor returning to one of these environments (kind of like Stephen King's It).

They learn that the consciousness gives off radiation to whoever is inside it.

They do this to children so that when they're around 8-years-old, they have developed leukemia or some other disease linked to radiation exposure and feed on their immature white blood cells caused by the exposure. Basically it takes the consciousness 8 years to 'prep' or 'fatten up' its victims for consuming.

My question is, going in and out of these environments for 8 years, maintaining hygiene (bathing regularly, washing their clothes), would the children leave any radiation behind? Could it linger in their homes, in their schools or be passed on to people around them?

Comment: As in your other question "radiation" is literally a spectrum.  Given that leukemia is specified, you _probably_ mean [ionizing radiation](https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/radiation/ionizing_radiation.html), but even there, there are _so many details_ you're leaving out that this question is largely unanswerable.  I should also point out that exposure to radiation generally [dramatically lowers white cell counts](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4209750) so unless your creatures are using radiation to _mask_ their eating white cells, exposing their food source to radiation is a bad idea.

Comment: @jdunlop "Radiation" isn't even a spectrum, so much as a description, like "square". Gravity is arguably a form of radiation. Light is radiation. *Sound* is acoustic radiation. Heck, since earthquakes are propagations of shockwaves in rock, *earthquakes* are technically a type of "radiation". The question does say "electromagnetic radiation"— But that includes visible light, radio waves, x-rays, and maybe magnetic fields and EMPs—  While arguably excluding types of ionizing radiation that would actually make more sense in causing cancer and radiation sickness, like beta or alpha particles.

Comment: Why have people voted to close this question? Are there that many people who don't understand how radiation works? Ignoring all the backstory, this is nothing more than, "If I've been exposed to radiation, can I then expose another to radiation?" JohnO's correct, it's a wonder this long after Hiroshima and Nagasaki that we still need to answer this question - but it's a very straightforward Real Life question with a satisfactory Worldbuilding context. Why's it getting closed? @jdunlop, what details do you think are missing?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact - given the OP's use of "radiation", it isn't at all clear what they mean by it.  If it's strictly EMR emitted by a mysterious creature, then the answer is obviously no.  But given what they describe this radiation doing, it could as easily be elemental transmutation or something that _does_ leave a permanent effect.  Without additional detail - and research - from the OP, I don't think the question can be meaningfully answered without making it trivial.

Comment: @jdunlop I apologize if I'm belaboring a point, but if what you were trying to do was help Luke ask a question that wasn't trivially answered, "no." (And that's the only answer there is to this question, even if "radiation" resulted only in a sunburn), then I think you confused the issue more than helped it. Personally, I think it's unfair to close the question simply because Luke's obviously using the post-1950's version of "radiation" on a Stack filled with engineers and scientists. But, fair enough, it's simply my opinion that it's obvious.

Comment: @jdunlop "If it's strictly EMR, then the answer is obviously no." I don't think that is quite right. It is possible (admittedly statistically unlikely) to transmute atomic elements using [EMR radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photofission). 

So if there is a low level background of X-ray/gamma rays (from memory both are EM radiation) at the right energies then it would cause cellular damage (potentially causing leukemia) as well as increasing the radioactivity emitted by the person. Which would irradiate the space around them.

Answer (score 1):

"Radiation" is little particles flitting through space *that do not stop*. They can't linger, and they travel at the speed of light... so they're gone in a hurry (except neutrons, but they travel at some large fraction of the speed of light, and then gone).

If radiation is a problem, it's because as soon as those particles are gone, more are on their way from a *source*. Some machine is sending out the radiation, or some natural phenomenon is producing it. This source could be some fancy science fiction device, or a lump of uranium ore.

When we say that some nuclear site is *contaminated*, it can't be contaminated by radiation. As above, the radiation is gone as soon as it's born. It's contaminated by a *source*. Usually uranium (though plausibly other elements... radium was a popular way to have your jaw rot off and get fatal cancers in the early 20th, but there are several others). That uranium (or whatever else) just sits there emitting new radiation until it finally sputters out a few million years later.

This entity, however it is emitting the radiation, is the source. The radiation itself will not contaminate the children... they can go home, and a Geiger counter won't even click in their presence. Though it might if near the entity.

This post covers the four basic types of radiation, and those are alpha, beta, gamma, and neutron radiation. There are other exotic types unsuited for your fiction, but even those really follow the rules I've laid out.

Comment: Just a couple of notes:  Alpha and beta radiation also travel at less then the speed of light (but not so you'd notice) Neutron radiation can transmute elements causing them to become sources of radiation.  However the question was explictly about "electromagnetic radiation" so let's assume gamma and X-rays.

Comment: @JamesK I often sit around thinking to myself "gee, that helium nucleus is pretty slow". But I get that the rest of you can't tell the difference, didn't want to confuse the guy. As for neutron radiation transmuting, my limited understanding of all things nuclear is that these are usually not very hot elements (unless they started out that way), and quickly decay. In other words, that doesn't really contaminate anyway (especially not at the levels where someone wouldn't die immediately from the neutron radiation).

Comment: To give one tenth of a point of credit to the education system (at least in the U.S.), too much of it was developed during the Cold War when the threat of *fallout* was considered very real - but not deadly enough (despite plenty of evidence to the contrary) to simply kill everyone. Fallout can be loosely (to the point of making angels weep) considered "contagious" in that you're walking around covered in dust that's radioactive, giving everyone you walk near cancer. But, having said that, you're nevertheless absolutely correct. 'Course, lots o'people think you get superpowers from radiation.